# Accessing multiple instances of a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I am creating a menu for a restaurant that can have 5 dishes of each category. So far I have created a class for meat dishes and I'm able to add up to 5 dishes, each with a unique identifier. What I am having trouble with is accessing the objects after they have been created. 
(There will be multiple categories hence why there is a switch statement with only one case so far).

For example, how would I implement a way to change the description of the second dish?

Here is my code so far:

meat.h

```
    class Meat{
private:
    int meatNumber;
    std::string meatCategory;
    std::string meatDescription[MAX_ITEMS];
    double meatPrice[MAX_ITEMS];

    public:
        Meat();
        //setter functions
        int setMeatNumber();
        std::string setMeatDescription();
        double setMeatPrice();

        //getter functions
        int getMeatNumber();
        std::string getMeatCategory();
        std::string getMeatDescription(int i);
        double getMeatPrice(int i);
    };
```

meat.cpp

```
#include "Meat.h"

//constructor
    Meat::Meat() {
    meatNumber = 0;
    meatCategory = "Meat";
    meatDescription[MAX_ITEMS] = "No description written.";
    meatPrice[MAX_ITEMS] = 0.0;
}

//setter functions
int Meat::setMeatNumber(){
    static int counter = 1;
    meatNumber = counter++;
}

    std::string Meat::setMeatDescription(){
        int i = 0;
        std::cout << "Please enter a short description: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> meatDescription[i];
        return meatDescription[i];
    }

    double Meat::setMeatPrice(){
        int i = 0;
        std::cout << "Please set the price in a 00.00 format: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "£";
        while(!(std::cin >> meatPrice[i])){
           std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
           std::cout << "Error. Please enter a number: ";
        }
        return meatPrice[i];
    }

    //getter functions
    int Meat::getMeatNumber() { return meatNumber; }
    std::string Meat::getMeatCategory() { return meatCategory; }
    std::string Meat::getMeatDescription(int i) {return meatDescription[i]; }
    double Meat::getMeatPrice(int i) { return meatPrice[i]; }
```

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "Meat.h"



int main() {
int choice;

    std::cout << "Menu Creation Terminal\n\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t Welcome\nto Wrapid™ Restaurants\n\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Add Meat Dish\n2. Add Fish Dish\n3. Add Vegetarian Dish\n4. Add Drink\n"
                 "5. Edit Current Menu\n6. Quit\n\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please select an option: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            {
            int option = true;
            int count = 0, i;
            Meat meatDish;
            std::cout << "Meat Dishes" << std::endl;
            while (true) {
                meatDish.setMeatNumber();
                meatDish.setMeatDescription();
                meatDish.setMeatPrice();

                //functions to add details to dish
                std::cout << "You have added the following dish: " << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Item number: \n" << meatDish.getMeatNumber() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Item Category: \n " << meatDish.getMeatCategory() << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Item Description: \n" << meatDish.getMeatDescription(i) << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Item Price: \n £" << meatDish.getMeatPrice(i) << std::endl;

                std::cout << "Would you like to add another item? Press 1 for yes or 2 for no: " << std::endl;
                std::cin >> option;
                count += 1;
                if (count == 5) {
                    std::cout << "Error. Exceeded maximum items.";
                    break;
                } //breaks out of loop if more than 5 items
                if (option == 2) { break; } //breaks out of loop when user is finished adding items
            }//while loop to contain menu
        }//brace for scope of case 1
}


return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using c++ class `Meat` you can use `[]` to instantiate N items

for example `5` objects

```
 Meat meats[5];
```

If you want to modify 2nd object then

```
 meats[1].setMeatDescription(<pass argument>);
```

You need to change that method using `this` keyword

```
 this->meatDescription = <pass argument>;
```

No need to create `meatDescription[]` as an array

use this code https://pastebin.com/bCkzbFZV you can use `meats[i].getMeatDescription()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed response and all the changes you made to the code. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class called DishesContainer. This class could have :

- a private std::vector => it will hold every instance
- a public function to create a new dish
- a public function to change any type of value inside a dish meat.

For exemple to change the description

```
class DishContainer{
public:
    void ChangeDescription(int indexMeat, std::string newDescription){
        meats_[indexMeat].setMeatDescription(newDescription);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Meat> meats_;
}
```